# Android Image Ratio 3 4 6 8

Tags: android

I am creating some graphics for my app and am stuck on the ratio. I understand the ratio for double values for example

```
ldpi = 75px/75px (quarter less than starting point)
mdpi = 100px/100px (starting point)
hdpi = 150px/150px (1.5 of starting point)
xhdpi = 200px/200px (2x starting point)
```

but what if the width and height aren't the same for example i seen a post on here that had values like this

```
ldpi = 240x320
mdpi = 320x480
```

The width uses the ratio but how does the 480 get to 320? a quarter of 320 = 80 but there is 160 diff between the heights

Answer (score 1):

Use the same multiplier (scale factor) for both X and Y:

- ldpi:    0.75
- mdpi:    1.0
- hdpi;    1.5
- xhdpi:   2.0
- xxhdpi:  3.0
- xxxhdpi: 4.0

Comment: 0.75 of 480 is 360 so why is it 320?

Comment: Because it's not well done? If you apply math correctly, it should be 240*360. They did it 320, so they didn't correctly apply the formula. Anyway, 240*320 is a **standard full screen** display for an ldpi device and 320*480 is a **standard full screen** display for an mdpi device.

Comment: Oh, yeah i thought it was the same formula but it was a well thumbed up post so i assumed his math was correct

Comment: Well, these images are FULL SCREEN backgrounds, probably. Not icons or such. Displays vary: typical phones: ldpi: 240x320, mdpi: 320x480, hdpi 480x800 **or** 480x854 **or** 960x540, xhdpi 1280x720 **or** 1280x800, ...